# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 in C

Tags: c, allegro5

Today I installed the Allegro game programming library for C and I’ve tried to include one of the header files but when I try to execute `gcc -I./include example.c -o a.exe` in the terminal, I keep on getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
     (maybe you meant: __al_mangled_main)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any ideas? I installed Allegro 5 using the instructions here: https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Install_Allegro5_From_GIT/OSX

**example.c code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){
    puts(“Hello, world!”);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is `*argv` const?

Comment: @Navin: You can `const` it if you want to. Nobody can force you to modify your argument vector.

Comment: @EOF I was just curious since that isn't the usual signature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[You need to link your executable to Allegro](https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=FAQ#Why_do_I_get_undefined_symbol_errors.3F).

According to the FAQ, you should add `-lallegro` to your compile command, or `-lallegro -lallegro_main` on OSX

You may need other flags, and Allegro 5 uses pkg-config instead of allegro-config, so do `pkg-config allegro-5.0 allegro_main-5.0 --cflags --libs` to find out.

You can combine this into a compiler command by using backticks, e.g.

```
$CC -W -Wall `pkg-config allegro-5.0 allegro_main-5.0 --cflags --libs` foo.c -o foo.exe
```

Comment: It works, thanks! However, I noticed that from the `pkg-config` command that allegro's header files are in `/usr/local/include`. Do I still need to include that as a flag when compiling or is that folder included in `PATH` seeing as it contains many other header files for other libraries?

Comment: @Calculus5000 It depends on the search path of your compiler - for example, GCC on a normal *nix platform will look in `/usr/local/include` (and various other locations) by default unless you tell it to look elsewhere. I believe clang is the same. So if you're using using GCC or clang you don't need to include it as a flag.

Comment: Also would it be possible to get a brief explanation on how that `pkg-config` command works?

Comment: @Calculus5000 `pkg-config` is a pretty standard tool that looks in certain locations for metadata with information about installed packages and libraries. Usually it is used for version info, linker flags, etc. When you did `make install` (or equivalent xcode command or whatever), one of the things that happened is the metadata for Allegro was copied to where `pkg-config` checks for that stuff (e.g. `/usr/share/pkgconfig/`, `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/`, any paths in `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`).

Comment: Awesome answer. In case it's helpful for anyone else, this helped me compile a similar script with g++. I was able to compile by running `g++ foo.cpp -o foo -lallegro_main -lallegro`. I had to have both -`lallegro` and `-lallegro_main`.